# Lock mysql database, when insert data more than one user at one time

Tags: java, mysql, id-generation

I'm creating an application using Java RMI. In my case, more than 10 users are adding data to the database. My application has a class `GenerateID` and it's on server side. For every user's id generation process is going through this class. It has a method named `generateID()`  I need to know, if more than one users are inserting data to the database at same time, What will be happening?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You could synchronize the method call and use a database transaction

Comment: So long as you're running the database server, it has multi connection  support built in

Comment: Thank you! the problm solved!